# Select2 field .value property doesn't change inside .onchange function

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, jquery-select2, onchange

I'm having this very specific issue of which I have not been able to find a solution.
I have a Select2 field on which after selecting a specific company it will auto fill with it's corresponding country based on values fetch from an API on a [.onchange](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/onchange) function triggered on a Select2 field from which you select the corresponding company to fetch from.

All other auto-filled fields apart from this one, get populated with it's corresponding value, except for the Select2 field for the country value that only gets selected but not displayed has chosen.

However, if I try to change the .value property outside the .onchange function, the field does change completely and display the currently selected country on the list.

I already tried executing the function either by changing the .value property with vanilla JavaScript and using the .val method with JQuery following the recommendations on the [Select2 documentation](https://select2.org/programmatic-control/events#limiting-the-scope-of-the-change-event), but the same result occurs, here I attach the code and some screenshots.

```
const countryField = document.querySelector(
    'select[name=' + country + ']'
)

selectField.onchange=function() {
    const apiUrl = new URL(url)
    const params = {q: $(this).val()}
    apiUrl.search = new URLSearchParams(params).toString();
    fetch(apiUrl)
        .then((response) => response.json())
        .then(function(data) {
            const fieldsToUpdate = [
                {field:addressLine1Field,value:data.address_line1},
                {field:addressLine2Field,value:data.address_line2},
                {field:cityDistrictField,value:data.city_district},
                {field:stateProvinceField,value:data.state_province},
                {field:postalCodeField,value:data.postal_code},
                {field:countryField,value:data.country},
            ]
            for (const { field,value } of fieldsToUpdate) {
                if (!!field) {
                    field.value = ''
                    if (!!value) {
                        field.value = value
                    }
                }
            }
        })
        .catch(function(error) {
           console.log(error);
        });
}
```

[image: Country is only selected on list but not display has selected.]

While changing the property outside the function results in this:

```
const countryField = document.querySelector(
    'select[name=' + country + ']'
)
countryField.value = 'Canada'
```

[image: Country is selected on the list and displayed has selected.]

So far I'm still not sure what makes the property change works different on the DOM while executing it inside the .onchange method.
If anyone out there might have any idea what it could be, any help would be appreciated.
Thank you all.

Answer (score 0):

This is working example.

```js
$('#company').select2();
$('#country').select2();

$('#company').on('select2:select', function (e) {
  $('#country').val('CA').trigger('change');

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/select2@4.1.0-beta.1/dist/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/select2@4.1.0-beta.1/dist/js/select2.min.js"></script>

Company
<select class="js-example-basic-single" name="state" id="company">
  <option value="1">XXX</option>
  <option value="2">YYY</option>
</select>
</br>
Country
<select class="js-example-basic-single" id="country" >
  <option value="AL">Alabama</option>
  <option value="WY">Wyoming</option>
  <option value="CA">Canada</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Executing $('select[name=' + country + ']').val('X').trigger('change'); as suggested on the [Select2 documentation](https://select2.org/programmatic-control/events#limiting-the-scope-of-the-change-event) either inside or outside the function gives the same result has shown before, I also tried replacing the .onchange function with a JQuery .change function, but using the .change function doesn't work on the company field, for some unknown reason the .change function is never triggered on the field, I don't know if the issue is related to the function method itself.

Comment: Using $('#company').on('select2:select', function (e) {} on my code doesn't, the select event is not triggered at all as suggested in the documentation, I'm using Select2  with @ttskch/select2-bootstrap4-theme package from NPM.